# Validate Jasypt encrypted password on PHP server

Tags: java, php, authentication, encryption, jasypt

I'm trying to implement a basic but secured log in process on my Java application.

The client fills his login/password on the application, the password is encrypted (or hashed?) with:

```
StrongPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();
String password = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(passwordTextField.getText());
```

and sent to my web server which processes the query using PHP.
The given string is stored in MySQL as the password at first connection (for test purpose at the moment).

Obviously, I need to check at every connection if the password matches what I have in the database.
I thought I could compare with some function the new password string to confirm if it matches the existing one in the DB.
Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do this.

I might be totally wrong on the way to do it but I can't find online resources that would give clues to manage a Java client authenticating on a PHP web server.

I have seen references to a GitHub project to get Jasypt stuff into PHP, but the references does not exist anymore.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Sorry I'm a total newbie on the security issues.

Thanks.